# Windows named pipe dropping messages

Tags: c++, named-pipes

I am trying to write a named pipe reader to consume events from another application that provides named pipe streaming. I've run into a problem where I do not receive all events from the named pipe server when it sends batches of events very quickly together.

To simplify the issue and isolate it from the other activity that is being done by the server application, I decided to cut it out and write a simple c++ console app that writes to a named pipe and have my code listen to that.

After creating the test application to send batches of **10** messages with a three second wait between batches. The server indicates success for every write operation, but in the end my named pipe reader is consistently only receiving **two** messages.

I tried adding in delays between read operations using Sleep(), and that had no effect. However, when I tried adding delays between write operations using Sleep() on the server, it allows me to receive the messages in the client.

With batches of 10, a 1ms Sleep() will generally allow me to get all messages. If I send larger batches, I have to increase that Sleep() a bit.

I tried reading with a simple C# app as well, and that did not improve my ability to read all events without delays between write operations.

This is extremely confusing to me, because as I understand it the pipes are supposed to function as FIFO, so I have no idea where these messages are going.

Does anyone have some insight into why these writes are successful, but I am unable to get all of them in the reader? Or why adding a small delay between the writes allows me to read them all just fine?

I have included the writer and reader code below. I removed error handling/validation code to simplify the readability of it. For the server side piece, I got the pipe definition from the production app I'm trying to consume so I made sure the creation was the same.

**Writer**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

#define BUFFER_SIZE 65535

int main()
{
    HANDLE namedPipeHandle;
    BOOL   fSuccess = FALSE;
    DWORD  bytesRead;

    wstring pipeName = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\TestPipe";

    namedPipeHandle = CreateNamedPipe(pipeName.c_str(),
                                      PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX |FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                                      PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,
                                      PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
                                      BUFFER_SIZE,
                                      BUFFER_SIZE,
                                      NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
                                      NULL);

    bool isConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(namedPipeHandle, NULL);

    DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
    string message = "TEST";
    int count = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            fSuccess = WriteFile(namedPipeHandle, message.c_str(), message.size(), &bytesWritten, NULL);

            if (fSuccess)
            {
                count++;
            }

            //Sleep(1); // Adding the Sleep(1) allows me to receive each batch of 10 in the client.
        }
        cout << "Sent " << count << " total messages" << endl;
        Sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

**Reader**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

#define BUFFER_SIZE 65535

int main()
{
    HANDLE hPipe;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    DWORD  bytesRead;
    wstring pipeName = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\TestPipe";

    hPipe = CreateFile(pipeName.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    int receivedCount = 0;
    int failedCount = 0;

    do
    {
        bool fSuccess;

        fSuccess = ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, &bytesRead, NULL);

        if (fSuccess)
        {
            receivedCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            failedCount++;
        }

        cout << "Total Events Received: " << receivedCount << endl;
        cout << "Total Events Failed: " << failedCount << endl;
    } while (true);

    CloseHandle(hPipe);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you specify `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` when you don't do any asynchronous read/write? It doesn't appear to me that you actually want to use this flag. _"If this mode is enabled, functions performing read, write, and connect operations that may take a significant time to be completed can return immediately."_

Comment: I matched the creation of the named pipe to the existing production app's specification, because I wanted to make sure that the behavior of the test pipe was as close as possible to the pipe I want my new app to read. The existing production app does use some asynchronous operations, but just for testing whether the message drop issue is present in a simplified environment, I didn't bother with an asynchronous write.

Comment: Why do you have the comment 'read from the pipe' when the next line of code *writes to* the pipe?

Comment: Whoops. Fixed that.Thanks @user207421

Comment: The reader does not have a shot at correctly identifying messages.  Without the sleep it is going to get multiple of them, no zero-terminator to separate them.  Call SetNamedPipeHandleState() to put it in message mode so *bytesRead* and the counter can be accurate.  NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT is not correct (meant for WaitNamedPipe).

Comment: @jeremyr Asynchronous vs Synchronous I/O on one side of the pipe is handled separately than the other side of the pipe.  Both parties do not have to use the same I/O model, they just have to agree on the pipe characteristics (message vs stream, duplex, etc). Don't use `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` unless you are really using Asynchronous I/O. Misusing `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` has bad consequences

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the info. By checking my bytesRead, the reader is definitely consuming more than one message at once. I tried using SetNamedPipeHandleState() in the reader and had to add GENERIC_WRITE access as well. It works as expected now. Please add an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Congratulations.  Be sure to write your own post to show what you did, mark it as the answer.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. I've tried calling SetNamedPipeHandleState() but it didn't work. @HansPassant Can you please elaborate more on this "The reader does not have a shot at correctly identifying messages"?